# Adding vertical limits line

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm trying to write the following in latex:

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use $A\big\vert_{x}$ as a guide, using another of the four `\big`-like commands to get an appropriate size

Comment: The is also `\left.` ... `\right|`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, esdiff} 

\begin{document}

\[ \diff{\boldsymbol{\mathcal W}(t)}{t} \biggr\rvert_{\mathbf{p',w}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]